# Is there unsigned Double in Swift?

Tags: swift

Forgive me if this is a silly question, I a self-taught programmer. If there is unsigned `Int` for large whole number storage, there should be an unsigned `Double` for storing large floating point number like `Double` right?

Comment: Having "signed" and "unsigned" variants of some types of variables is not automatically extendable to *all* types. For instance, there is no signed "string" or "bool" type -- it "makes no sense". That goes for `Double` as well.

Comment: I understand it is not automatically extandable, but I am thinking if there is an unsigned `Double` type a even larger number can be stored inside it.

Comment: "Even larger" is only **one** single extra bit. For the purpose of a floating point number, that extra precision is just Not Worth The Effort.

Comment: Ah -- just came up with a rational argument. The behavior of subtracting a large unsigned integer type from a smaller one is well-defined: the result is what one would expect with a 1-bit larger type, but the extra bit gets discarded. However, for floating point numbers you cannot tack on a new bit (be it `0` or `1`) without radically changing its value.

Comment: You can use NSDecimalNumber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Swift Standard Library Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/NumericTypes.html), if a `Double` (aka `Float64`) does not give you enough precision, you can use a `Float80`. But I have to wonder what it is that are you trying to store that exceeds the capabilities of a `Double`.

Answer (score 3):

It's because [floating point formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), like `Double` is one, don't support unsigned numbers. Also just because you've got the possibility to use `unsigned` on some types like `Int` doesn't mean, that it has to work with others too.

Comment: Foundation of CS is definity important. I will read them all, thank you for your clarification